# Log into application that uses kerberos

Tags: loadrunner, vugen

Supposedly I have a webpage, where I got the authentication popup [The very same as those web pages that uses basic authentication]. However, the server is using Kerberos for authentication. As such, is there a way I can retrieve the response with VUGen? Because I tried to use the conventional way of using 'web_add_header("Authorization","[password]")', as well as using 'web_set_user("username, password, hostname:80")' but I kept getting 401.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the [online help](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/lr/en/2020-2020_SP1/help/function_reference/FuncRef.htm#FuncRef/web/lrFr_web_set_user.htm) of web_set_user api, and ensure username is in the form of domain\user, e.g. "mansfield\freddy".

Besides, it's suggested to set socket option as KERBEROS.

```
// Turn on pre-emptive authentication for web server. The pre-emptive authenticate scheme is always “KERBEROS”.
web_set_sockets_option("INITIAL_AUTH","KERBEROS");
```

Answer (score 0):

1. web_add_header could override the authentication info generated by web_set_user, so please use web_set_user only
2. maybe you should use domain name with your username
3. please compare the snapshot of extended log with the network traffic of manual operation (you may capture it by wireshark or fiddler) and see what is the difference.